# Nuxt.js router config at runtime or just before the application starts

Tags: docker, runtime, nuxt.js, config, router

**TL;DR** Is it possible to set the Nuxt.js router-base configuration at runtime or just before the app starts and not at build-time?

In my `nuxt.config.js` I have : `router: { base: process.env.APP_CONTEXT_PATH }`

The `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install


COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

I set the `APP_CONTEXT_PATH` environment variable in the `docker-compose.yml`. After running `docker-compose up`, the app is indeed only available at `<HOST>:<PORT>/<APP_CONTEXT_PATH>`.
**But** the router-base is still set to `<HOST>:<PORT>/` i.e. all necessary Nuxt.js scripts and all routes are relative to `<HOST>:<PORT>/` and not to `<HOST>:<PORT>/<APP_CONTEXT_PATH>`

How can I solve this problem?

When I set the variable in the `Dockerfile` e.g. `ENV APP_CONTEXT_PATH=/app/`, everything works fine but I don't want to rebuild the image every time I have to change the context path.

Thanks in advance! :-)